# Swift 3 export SecKey to String

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, public-key-encryption, seckeyref

I am developing an iOS app using swift 3.

I need to export an `SecKey` (which is the user RSA publickey reference) to a string (e.g base64) in order to share it through a generated QRCode.

It also has to work the other way since the other user that scans the `QRCode`, will be able to rebuild a `SecKey` reference from the string extracted from the QRCode.

I found few tutorials but I don't understand exactly what I need to extract from the `SecKey` reference, and I don't know how to convert it to a `String`.

Comment: Can you get the SecKey` as `Data`? Once you have `Data`, getting a base64 string is easy.

Comment: Do you really need to use that tricky `SecKey` class of yours? After reading [this detailed question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408825/can-i-get-the-modulus-or-exponent-from-a-seckeyref-object-in-swift/43225656#43225656) I don't think there is an easy hack around this :-(

Comment: @PauloMattos unfortunately, yes. The cryptographic libraries I am using require a SecKey object, as I am generating those keys from the app.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Export Key (iOS 10 only)**

```
var error:Unmanaged<CFError>?
if let cfdata = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(publicKey!, &error) {
   let data:Data = cfdata as Data
   let b64Key = data.base64EncodedString()
}
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30662270/5276890 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/27935528/5276890 for longer ways which probably support iOS < 10.

**Reimport Key**

```
guard let data2 = Data.init(base64Encoded: b64Key) else {
   return
}

let keyDict:[NSObject:NSObject] = [
   kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
   kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
   kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: NSNumber(value: 512),
   kSecReturnPersistentRef: true as NSObject
]

guard let publicKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(data2 as CFData, keyDict as CFDictionary, nil) else {
    return
}
```

Note: This generates a base64 key and not a certificate. A lot of code samples online deal with how to generate a public key from a certificate using SecCertificateCreateWithData

Also: 512 bit is fast to generate but worthless. Pick a longer and secure value once you're satisfied with the results.

I got valid results back when importing the key I generated and exported, so I assume it works, but I did not try to encrypt and decrypt with it.

Comment: I'm going to try that tomorrow. On the reimport, is `cfdata` the base64 string ?

Comment: oops. Sorry. I was lazy and didn't bother generating Data from String and CFData from Data. Can you handle that? Otherwise I'll try and add the code later today.

Comment: Never mind. I've just edited the code. Damn the 5 minute limit on comments!

Comment: Thank you, it works for exporting public key string, and I reuse it for exporting private key as well.

Comment: There is also the official documentation by Apple for converting between `SecKey` and `Data`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_as_data

Comment: @Nickkk this question is six years old. As the one who answered the question, I don't recall this documentation existing back then. Also, swift was rapidly evolving back then. IIRC, Swift 2 was very different from 3. Things only slowed down in versions 4 and 5.