# In Symmetric encryption where Alice and Bob message each other, how can both decrypt the same data?

Tags: ios, security, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am building a messaging app where one client can message another.

There will be 2 clients - Alice and Bob. Alice needs to be able to send an encrypted message to Bob and vice versa.

These encrypted messages will need to be stored on a server so that Alice and Bob apps can retrieve them. However, only Alice and Bob apps should be able to decrypt the messages.

**IMPORTANT: Both Alice and Bob should be able to decrypt all messages between each other. Also neither Alice, nor Bob should be storing decrypted data on their devices. Both should be fetching the encrypted data from server, then decrypting it as needed.**

The server shouldn't be able to decrypt the data. Nor should a 3rd party Mallory be able to decrypt the data between Alice and Bob. The server shouldn't have access to any secret/private keys. The server should only store the sender, the receiver, and the encrypted content itself.

I know that I shouldn't use asymmetric encryption for encrypting large quantities of data. This has been explained here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/using_keys_for_encryption

which states:

> Asymmetric encryption doesn’t require a shared secret. On the other hand, it’s computationally expensive and works only on small, discrete blocks of data. Therefore, it’s most suitable for small transfers when sender and receiver have no established relationship.

> Symmetric encryption is good for bulk data transfer because it’s computationally efficient and operates on streams of data. But it works only when the transmitter and the receiver share a secret key. So you typically rely on some other technique, such as asymmetric encryption or the Diffie-Hellman key exchange, to share a key and establish a session.

> When the sender and receiver share a single, secret key, they can perform symmetric encryption, in which the same key both encrypts and decrypts the message. Even though the operations in this case are computationally efficient, initially sharing the key poses its own challenge. For that reason, you’ll usually want to use another method, such as asymmetric encryption, to exchange a symmetric key at the time you begin communicating.

> On the encryption side, instead of simply padding and encoding the given block of data with the key, the SecKeyCreateEncryptedData(*:*:*:*:) function first generates a random Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) session key. It uses this key to encrypt the input data, and then RSA encrypts the AES key using the input public key you provide. It finally assembles the RSA encrypted session key, the AES encrypted data, and a 16-byte AES-GCM tag into a block of data that it returns to you. On the decryption side, the process is reversed. The function decrypts the AES session key using the private key you provide as input and then uses that to decrypt the data.

It's the last few sentences here which I am having problems with. It explains how in order for Alice to send encrypted data to Bob, Alice can use the `SecKeyCreateEncryptedData` to generate a random AES session key to encrypt the data, and RSA encrypts this random AES session key using Bob's public key. On Bob's side, Bob decrypts and gets this random AES session key using his private key and then uses it to decrypt the data.

This allows Bob to get the decrypted data which Alice sent.

However, how would Alice decrypt this same data? I don't want Alice to be storing the decrypted data before sending it. The encrypted data should only be stored on server and both Alice and Bob should fetch it from there, and decrypt it.

Is my thinking flawed? Is there some other way I can achieve this?

Comment: You can't rely on an AES session key in your scenario as that key is ephemeral. The party that imitates the conversation (say Alice) need to explicitly generate a symmetric key and store it securely (Call it "AliceandBob"). You can then use asymmetric encryption to share this key with Bob (who also stores it as "AliceandBob").  Then this symmetric key is used to encrypt all communications between the pair.

Comment: @Paulw11 that's kind of what I was thinking I might need to do. Is it okay then for whosoever public key is "first" in ascending order to generate this symmetric key, store it, and send it to other using asymmetric encryption? Otherwise, how should it be decided who needs to create this key? I feel a bit like I am reinventing a wheel. Isn't this type of exchange fairly common use case in messaging apps and thus documented somewhere? I tried researching but there's too many irrelevant articles.

Comment: Normally the party that is initiating the communication would generate the key.  A key isn't needed until the first time Alice messages Bob or Bob messages Alice. When one party wants to communicate with the other, they first check their key store. If they don't have the required key then they generate it and send it to the other party. You are right that this is complex and you should always be wary when you create security systems. It is difficult to get right. You could look at /https://core.telegram.org/api/end-to-end to get an idea of how complex this is

Comment: Note that Telegram doesn't use asymmetric encryption at all as this requires a trust framework for the exchange of public keys.

Comment: You might be able to leverage this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53807792/how-to-implement-asymmetric-cryptography-for-distributed-app-where-keys-can-both

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about [security.se] or [crypto.se] but not programming. It is possible for an entity to encrypt the AES key twice, with both public keys.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Should I have posted this on Crypto StackExchange?

Comment: I found this solution using Diffie Hellman key exchange to be very helpful: https://gist.github.com/mehmeteminkartal/e2d1ee56526dc032b7257aef80c40d16

Comment: @sudoExclamationExclamation I'm struggling a bit with it. That it is not yet about programming is clear. I think you can post this on [crypto.se], but as it is very much an introductory question for which it is hard to search for dupes, I'm slightly afraid for its reception. I'd go for it. Please notify me here after posting the question on crypto. I'm a moderator at [crypto.se].

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Note that I may have found my answer in a programming related answer which I shared the GitHub link for (one using Diffie Hellman key exchange). I posted it on Cryptography in case I am doing something wrong: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/109467/in-symmetric-encryption-where-alice-and-bob-message-each-other-how-can-both-dec?noredirect=1#comment234741_109467