# What is eciesEncryptionCofactorVariableIVX963SHA512AESGCM in iOS SecKeyCreateEncryptedData?

Tags: ios, security, encryption, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I am looking at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53807793/1634905

When using Elliptic Curve key pair, it has the following:

```
private let keyType = kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom // kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom
private let algorithm = SecKeyAlgorithm.eciesEncryptionCofactorVariableIVX963SHA512AESGCM
private let keySize = 384
```

The `algorithm` is used in the `SecKeyCreateEncryptedData` function.

What is `eciesEncryptionCofactorVariableIVX963SHA512AESGCM` here?

Apple's doc doesn't explain it much:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/seckeyalgorithm/2874226-eciesencryptioncofactorvariablei

I see there are other possible options such as `eciesEncryptionCofactorVariableIVX963SHA384AESGCM`. Why did that SO answer pick the one with SHA512 when it picked 384 as the `keySize`?